# Office Addin - Launch Word from within Excel

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have had a feature request for my Excel Addin (office-js) to export data from Excel directly to Word. The workflow after execute (from within Excel) would be:
1. User selects table within Excel;
2. MS Word Opens a template document;
3. The table from Excel is copied into a specific location within the Word document

I have examined the API as well as available examples and haven't come across the ability to do this. There are alternative workflows I can explore but just wanted to confirm if this was possible.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it in VBA? if you can, this should be a new feature ask, and then you could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563. and upvote for this feature. thanks for your support